# How to clear the static content cache of JRun

Tags: caching, static, jrun

How can I clear the cache used by JRun for static content?
We use LCDS (that runs on JRun), and serve some SWF files with it.
When replacing SWFs with newer versions, we would like the new versions of the SWFs to be served, without restarting JRun/LCDS. this is because we don't want any downtime.
Many thanks!